# Angularjs add new field in for loop error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add a new "field" ( not sure if it's called as field ) in an array,
but it stops at a certain number. For example, I have 33 objects in the array, it stops at the 7th object.

My JS:

```
    if ($scope.all[i].CATEGORY == 'Community')
       {
           $scope.community.push($scope.all[i]);
           $scope.community[i].visibility = true;
           console.log($scope.community[i])
       }
```

The error it throws me

[image]

PS: Visibility doesn't exist in my object, I am adding it in

More info :

When i console log the whole array it returns me with 33 object

```
                if ($scope.all[i].CATEGORY == 'Community')
                {
                    $scope.community.push($scope.all[i]);
                    console.log($scope.community)                      
                }
```

But when i console log it with the [i] loop

```
                if ($scope.all[i].CATEGORY == 'Community')
                {
                    $scope.community.push($scope.all[i]);
                    console.log($scope.community[i])  <----                    
                }
```

I get 6 returns with 27 undefined returns ..

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Objects does not have a property named visiblility , you should be able to handle with the following code,

```
 if ($scope.all[i].CATEGORY == 'Community')
 {
    $scope.community.push($scope.all[i]);
    if($scope.community && $scope.community[i]){
    $scope.community[i].visibility = true;
    console.log($scope.community[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, now it doesn't have the error anymore. But why does it loop till the 7th array only?

Comment: Oh, and to add on, the object doesn't have visibility to begin with. I am adding it into my object.